# How to use PostgreSQL transaction in vapor

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor

I used the vapor in the [postgresql](https://github.com/vapor-community/postgresql-provider) ,I want to save a lot of data at once
,but I don't how to use postgresql transaction,Who can give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Fluent](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/fluent/database/#transactions) (Vapor's database ORM with support for PostgresQL) then you simply use:

```
drop.database?.transaction { conn in
  try modelToSave.makeQuery(conn).save()
  try nextModelToSave.makeQuery(conn).save()
}
```

Comment: hi,I want to know what the difference between it and 'mode.database?.transaction'

Comment: The model also holds a static reference to the database. `Model.database?.transaction` should be identical to `drop.database?.transaction`.